# Windows Formアプリケーション(C#)のライセンス管理で良い方法はありますか？

Tags: c#

Windows Formアプリケーション(.Net C#)をwindowsパソコンにインストールして利用して頂く際に
ライセンス管理をしたいと考えています。

アプリケーションの仕様
･windows 7/8/10上での動作を想定
･windowsサーバに接続してアプリケーションで利用するデータを取得する。(WCFを検討）

ライセンス管理方法案
･インストールできる台数を制限する。
･サーバに同時接続できるアプリ数を制限する。
･ClickOnceのテクノロジーでダウンロード数の制限をかける。

サーバで管理する、ローカルで制御するなど方法はいろいろあるかと存じますが、
何か良い方法をご存知の方がおりましたら、
参考URL等の情報でも構いませんのでご教示頂きたく、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ClickOnceのテクノロジーでダウンロード数の制限をかけることは、できますでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

お目汚しでございますが(実績に基づいた回答はできていません)、メモ程度の内容を記載します。実際に利用するには追加調査等が必要です。

ライセンス管理について:
資料を見かけた程度の情報しかありませんが、.NET Framework が提供するLicenseManagerというクラスがあるようです。
そのほかの解決策として、あまり高額ではないソフトウェアでファイルベースのライセンス認証を行うコードなどが以下のサイトにありました。ライセンスファイルをWCFを利用してネットワーク経由で取得するというのも良いでしょう。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624149/license-for-c-sharp-desktop-application

同時利用制限について:
利用時の制限については、WCFで可能のように思います。注意点としては同時接続数の管理や、セキュリティを適用する(不特定多数からのアクセス)場合、公的証明機関から証明書の取得が必須になることです。
オフラインで同時利用制限を課したい場合は、ライセンスサーバーを準備させるか、ハードウェアキーでの制限が考えられます。

ライセンス回避の対策:
ソフトウェアという資源のため、ライセンス認証を回避されることがあります(逆アセンブル等をされやすい)。費用が掛かりますがハードウェアキーを利用する等の対策をとることも可能です。
一般的には難読化や、ネイティブコードへの変換が考えられます。併せて、複数のDLLから成るソフトウエアであるのならば署名を追加することでDLL入れ替えを防ぐことは可能と考えています(このときアセンブリバージョンの変更は要注意)。

Comment: 同時利用の制限について、WCFを利用した場合、社内のシステムでも
必ず公的証明期間からの証明書が必要になりますか？
（ClickOnceアプリを検討していますが、ClickOnceでの配布の際は有効期限等の問題があるため、証明書をつけないようにする予定です。）

Comment: 不特定多数の利用で、インターネット経由での配布でかつ、WCFのバインディングでの暗号化を前提とした回答でした。そのため、社内システムである場合においては、公的証明機関からの証明書取得は不要です。証明書サーバーがあるならそこで発行したものを使えば良く、ActiveDirectory があるのならば、Windows認証を使用できます。自己証明書を使用するのは手間がかかるので良くないとだけ、コメントしておきます。

Comment: WCFで同時接続数を管理する場合、社内システムなのでhttps通信をしないで
http通信のみであれば、証明書自体が不要と考えておりますが
間違っていないでしょうか。

Comment: セキュリティを適用しない場合、証明書は不要である認識です(要検証)。(備考: [WsHttpBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms731346(v=vs.110).aspx) で security mode=Message とし、clientCredentialType=UserNameを指定した場合は何らかの証明書が必要となってしまいます)

Answer (score 1):

ライセンス管理するということは、ライセンス対価、つまり課金処理と連動すると思うのですが。しかし、質問はライセンスに終始している点が気になります。

課金体系を設計すれば、自ずとライセンス管理も定まりませんか？ （クライアントインストール数なのか同時接続数なのか等）

Comment: 課金体系はまだ決まってません。。決めないといけないですね。。ただ、インストール数、またはサーバへの同時接続数でユーザー数を管理したいと考えております。前者だとインストールできる端末は限られるイメージで後者であればどの端末にもインストールはできるますがアプリの同時利用者数は限定できることになります。